# Solidity - deploy and verificate

Tags: solidity

I have 3  contract, all they uses SafeMath libraries and a couple of my. I connect them all (library to contract) and everything works (I work in REMIX)
so how do I deploy all these 3 contracts with all my libraries and then verificate in etherscan all contracts? I need deploy 3 contract separately, and all my library separately. Beacouse i will write more contract that will use same libraries. And all need to be verificated.

---

I dont understand, beacouse to verificate contract we need send all code with library, but i connect library from other file.